# should I edit dist/index.js or dist/index.es.js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to patch a javascript library

(The library has a pull request which is long standing for half a year)

I find same code in `slate-react/dist/index.js` and `slate-react/dist/index.es.js`.
Well I can edit both of them, but which one should I change?

Is `*.es.js` is compiled into `*.js` ?

Comment: What library is it ?

Comment: `slate-react`, as far as I can tell, shouldn't have a `dist` directory at all. It has a `src` directory containing the source code and generates a `lib` directory containing the compiled JS.

Comment: looks like ecmascript module thingy. without the whole library to see how the `es.js` file got generated is quite difficult for me to say anything. But, these days, those things usually are generated. so, I think, you should modify the `*.js`.

Comment: You should clone the repository, check out the pull request branch that edited the *source* code, and then *build* locally. This will probably update both of the distributed files.